# Pulling events from google calendar in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

So I've a google calendar with public events on it and I want to be able to pull an event list from it into my app. I've a few questions/concerns. 
Does user of my app need to have a calendar app installed? Also, I couldn't find an API for this purpose, may be I looked at the wrong place or something :/
Please note that I don't want the events to be pulled from the calendar of the device. It should work regardless of a user having a calendar app. May be this is too wishful, in that case what's the closest thing I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html ?

Comment: I looked at it but I'm not sure if thats what I want. Besides I tried using class `CalendarService` but couldn't include the parent class. So not sure.

Answer (score 0):

GData isn't compatible with Android, you should use [`Calendar API`](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html)